# How should static weaving be done in EclipseLink recent versions like 4.0.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Hello my project uses EclipseLink as Jpa provider. My objective is to now use Java 17 and EclipseLink 4.0.0 but here I am getting an error class file for org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedRest not found

I tried looking into https://github.com/empulse-gmbh/eclipselink-static-weave-plugin

which says this way is for Java 8 and EclipseLink 2.5.1 Moreover it uses a plug in

```
<groupId>de.empulse.eclipselink</groupId>
<artifactId>staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

which is of 10 years ago and no updates.
My project works fine with these versions but I have a requirement to upgrade to newer versions. So how should I proceed. How should I do the static weaving. Please help.

Comment: That looks like a maven plugin someone wrote once and never needed to come back to. I believe there are other forks, but all it seems to be calling is described at https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving#Use_the_Command_Line so you should be able to do the same yourself with your build tool of choice (or update the maven plugin appropriately).